# Oracle 11g odp.net driver issues with Null value

Tags: c#, null, oracle11g, odp.net, dbnull

I am having issues comparing null values with oracle 11g odp.net driver. It works fine with oracle 10g odp.net driver. If a column is null in the database, then in datarow it has a string value of `null`.

This code fails:

```
int parentId =  row[PARENTID] != DBNull.Value ? int.Parse(row[PARENTID].ToString()) : 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hows does the code fail? (Failing and not working expected are slightly different cases...)

Comment: What I mean is the value of row[PARENTID].ToString = "null" instead of null. So when it tries to Parse it as an integer. I get an exception. "Input string is not in correct format"

Comment: What is the type of `row[PARENTID]`? If it is `string` or `object` and if the value *is really null* then that would throw a NullReferenceException (*unless* someone snuck in an extension method!). Perhaps the data stored *is* the string "null"? (Or there is something broken, or a flag, in the adapter...)

Comment: @pst what I learn from other users is Oracle is now spending "null" value if the column is null in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here :

```
var para6 = new OracleParameter("pOrganizationParentId", OracleDbType.Long){
    IsNullable = true,
};

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(organizationParentId)) {
    para6.Value = null; 
} else {
    para6.Value = long.Parse(organizationParentId);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This has something to do with the ORacle11g.
Like what you said, instead of real null value, it is a null string. 
If you are checking from OracleDbType,  the null in OracleDbType and CLR Datatype both inherits from INullable so below was my solution:

> ((INullable) rowParamDBType.Value).IsNull

To have a cleaner solution, you can place this in extension.

If your row is a DbType, you can check for param.Value==DbNull.Value.

---

While the above will work too, the real solution to this problem is use the **OracleDbTypeEx** instead of OracleDbType in your OracleParameter declaration. OracleDbTypeEx will return the value to DBType and because of this it will recognize the DBNull. See example code below.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = "param_out",
                                OracleDbTypeEx = OracleDbType.Decimal,
                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                            });

if (command.Parameters["param_out"].Value != Convert.DBNull)
{
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fromm the Oracle documentation:

f the value is a DbType, you can check for param.Value==DbNull.Value

If the value is an OracleDbType, you can check for ((INullable)param.Value).IsNull since Oracle Types inherit INullable interface.